# Loop in WildCard as Input of Script

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, for

I want to use my script on many files sometimes.

I used this for the purpose:

```
for etminput in $1
do
    #process
done
```

But this just gives the first input.
How can I do the process on every wildcard matches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to loop over all the arguments to your script, in any Bourne like shell, it's:

```
for i do
  something with "$i"
done
```

You could also do:

```
for i in "$@"; do
  something with "$i"
done
```

but it's longer and not as portable (though is for modern shells).

Note that:

```
for i; do
  something with "$i"
done
```

is neither Bourne nor POSIX so should be avoided (though it works in many shells)

---

For completeness, in non-Bourne shells:

#### csh/tcsh

```
@ i = 1
while ($i <= $#argv)
  something with $argv[$i]:q
  @ i++
end
```

You cannot use:

```
foreach i ($argv:q)
  something with $i:q
end
```

because that skips empty arguments

#### rc/akanga

```
for (i) something with $i
```

(`rc` generally is what shells *should* be like).

#### es

```
for (i=$*) something with $i
```

(es is rc on steroids).

#### fish

```
for i in $argv
  something with $i
end
```

#### zsh

Though it will accept the Bourne syntax, it also supports shorter ones like:

```
for i ("$@") something with "$i"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

n=1
echo "$0 got $# args..."
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ;do
  echo "$n: $1"
  shift
  n=$(( $n + 1 ))
done
```

Alternatively, look up 'Listing arguments with $* and $@'
in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html
which will elaborate on many aspects of these.